# Split string with only first instance java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I have the below response from some telnet server

```
String response = "I:BARCO@noiclt22815||K:CMS||O:REgetPerspectiveList||A0:googleP||A1:yahooP||A2:gmail||A3:test||A4:hello||A16:CCTV Barco||A17:CCTV: Corridor CC||A18:CCTV: DR Andy Warhol||A19:CCTV: DR Gaudi (Analog)||A20:CCTV: DR Miro||A21:CCTV: Entrance CC||A22:CCTV: Gaudi Demo Room Megapixel||";
```

I want to get the attributes value for e.g A0, A1 etc and therefore I write the below logic

```
String[] strings = response.split("[||]");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (String string : strings) {
    if (string.contains(":")) {
        String[] attributes = string.split(":");
        if (attributes[0].startsWith("A")) {
            list.add(attributes[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

But my problem is that string.split(":") split gives me string array but I requires only two length size string array only. For e.g. response A17 attribute gives me "CCTV" as attributes[1] and "Corridor CC" as attributes[2] but I requires "CCTV: Corridor CC" as attribute [1] only.

What regular expression I should write in string.split(regexp) so that string can be split based on first instance of colon operator only with exactly two length size string array.

Comment: You can use substring methods with indexOf to get the index of the first `:` and use substring till  that index and put the two strings in array.

Comment: I can do that but I want regex.

Comment: Pranav, it gives me same response as before means CCTV only for a17 attribute

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.* -- Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: *"If you can do something without a regular expression, that is probably the better way to do it"*

Comment: It's definitely not a duplicate of *that* question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below splits on pipes first, and *then* uses a regex to extract out the properties and attributes.  Note that even there, you could probably get away with doing another split.

```
String response = "I:BARCO@noiclt22815||K:CMS||O:REgetPerspectiveList||A0:googleP||A1:yahooP||A2:gmail||A3:test||A4:hello||A16:CCTV Barco||A17:CCTV: Corridor CC||A18:CCTV: DR Andy Warhol||A19:CCTV: DR Gaudi (Analog)||A20:CCTV: DR Miro||A21:CCTV: Entrance CC||A22:CCTV: Gaudi Demo Room Megapixel||";
String[] metaParts = response.split("\\|\\|");

for (int i=0; i < metaParts.length; ++i) {
    String property = metaParts[i].replaceAll("(.*):(.*)", "$1");
    String attribute = metaParts[i].replaceAll("(.*):(.*)", "$2");
    System.out.println(property + ":" + attribute);
}
```

As others here have said, regular expressions are not a panacea to cure all your development problems.  And splitting is definitely doing the heavy lifting for this problem.

Comment: It really feels like this is a lot of work to accomplish something that regex perhaps really *shouldn't* be accomplishing...

Answer (score 1):

[Set a limit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) on your split.

```
String[] attributes = string.split(":", 2);
```

This will force the regex to only be applied once (per the documentation it's applied n-1 times), so your groupings will only split on the colon character one time.

Once applied into the code, the result is as follows:

```
[googleP, yahooP, gmail, test, hello, CCTV Barco, CCTV: Corridor CC, CCTV: DR Andy Warhol, CCTV: DR Gaudi (Analog), CCTV: DR Miro, CCTV: Entrance CC, CCTV: Gaudi Demo Room Megapixel]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestRegex {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String response = "I:BARCO@noiclt22815||K:CMS||O:REgetPerspectiveList||A0:googleP||A1:yahooP||A2:gmail||A3:test||A4:hello||A16:CCTV Barco||A17:CCTV: Corridor CC||A18:CCTV: DR Andy Warhol||A19:CCTV: DR Gaudi (Analog)||A20:CCTV: DR Miro||A21:CCTV: Entrance CC||A22:CCTV: Gaudi Demo Room Megapixel||";
    Matcher mat = Pattern.compile("([^\\:]+)\\:([^\\|]+)\\|\\|").matcher(response);
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap();
    while( mat.find() ) {
        if(mat.groupCount() > 0) {
            String k = response.substring( mat.start(1), mat.end(1));
            String v = response.substring( mat.start(2), mat.end(2));
            hm.put(k, v);

            System.out.println(k +  " => " + v);   // debug
        }
    }
    // you may refer to your data from hashmap hm here!
    System.out.println(hm.get("K"));
}

} // end class
```